# Getting the return value of Javascript code in Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium2 for some automated tests of my website, and I'd like to be able to get the return value of some Javascript code.  If I have a `foobar()` Javascript function in my webpage and I want to call that and get the return value into my Python code, what can I call to do that?

Answer (score 204, accepted):

To return a value, simply use the `return` JavaScript keyword in the string passed to the `execute_script()` method, e.g.

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> wd = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> wd.get("http://localhost/foo/bar")
>>> wd.execute_script("return 5")
5
>>> wd.execute_script("return true")
True
>>> wd.execute_script("return {foo: 'bar'}")
{u'foo': u'bar'}
>>> wd.execute_script("return foobar()")
u'eli'
```

Comment: if the variable is not defined by javascript, what would be the return value?Does it throw an exception or simply an empty string ?

Comment: if variable is not defined, it returns `None`

Comment: quick note for those newbs, `return_value = wd.execute_script("return {foo: 'bar'}")` would store the returned value to be used later in your program.

Comment: the [doc](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script) lacks specifying a **Retruns:** note. Although in teir **Usage:** sample they put a js which returns the document title. Better to explicitly specify **Retruns:** in their doc

Answer (score 20):

You can return values even if you don't have your snippet of code written as a function like in the below example code, by just adding `return var;` at the end where var is the variable you want to return.

```
result = driver.execute_script('''
cells = document.querySelectorAll('a');
URLs = [];
[].forEach.call(cells, function (el) {
    URLs.push(el.href)
});
return URLs
''')
```

`result` will contain the array that is in `URLs` this case.