# Running javascript in Selenium using Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I am totally new to Selenium. I want to execute a javascript snippet in the following code(as commented in the code), but can't do so. Please help.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

patch = raw_input("Enter patch number\n")
rel = raw_input("Enter release\n")
plat = raw_input("Enter port\n")

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")

pdtfamily = browser.find_element_by_id("prodFamilyID")
pdtfamily.send_keys("Database & Tools" + Keys.TAB)
time.sleep(5)

pdt = browser.find_element_by_id("productID")
pdt.send_keys("Intelligent Agent" + Keys.TAB)
time.sleep(5)

pdt1 = browser.find_element_by_id("patchCacheChkBxID")
pdt1.send_keys(Keys.SPACE)
time.sleep(5)

pdt7 =  browser.find_element_by_id("M__Idf")
pdt7.send_keys(plat)

pdt8 =  browser.find_element_by_id("M__Idg")
pdt8.send_keys("American English")

# Here I want to execute this javascript - "submitForm('patchCacheAdd',1,{'event':'ok'});return false"

browser.close()
```

If I use -

```
selenium.GetEval("submitForm('patchCacheAdd',1,{'event':'ok'});return false")
```

it errors out as -

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GetEval'I
```

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Try `browser.execute_script` instead of `selenium.GetEval`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585343/getting-the-return-value-of-javascript-code-in-selenium/5585345#5585345) for example.

Answer (score 78):

You can use `execute_script`, here's a python example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794087/running-javascript-in-selenium-using-python") 
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('comment-user')[0].click()")
```

Comment: A comment to test the code above

Answer (score 8):

If you move from iframes, you may get lost in your page, best way to execute some jquery without issue (with selenimum/python/gecko):

```
# 1) Get back to the main body page
driver.switch_to.default_content()

# 2) Download jquery lib file to your current folder manually & set path here
with open('./_lib/jquery-3.3.1.min.js', 'r') as jquery_js: 
    # 3) Read the jquery from a file
    jquery = jquery_js.read() 
    # 4) Load jquery lib
    driver.execute_script(jquery)
    # 5) Execute your command 
    driver.execute_script('$("#myId").click()')
```