# Execute flash method for flash element

Tags: python, flash, selenium

I have a flash editor that should be opened and closed in my autotests, but have a problem with flash of course. What I try to do:

```
def open_browser(self, profile):
    global driver, testcase, Ui
    # driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
    driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
        desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.implicitly_wait(0.1)
    return driver


from com.thoughtworks.selenium.FlashSelenium import FlashSelenium
import unittest
import time
from selenium import webdriver

class SmokeTests(unittest.TestCase):
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    global driver, Ui, Base, UiNodes, MyFormsPage, actions, PmailPage, SharePage, FlashSelenium, flash
    Base = BaseTest()
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    # profile.set_preference('plugin.state.flash', 0)
    # profile.update_preferences()
    driver = Base.open_browser(profile)
    Ui = UiHelper(driver)
    UiNodes = link.UINodes()
    PmailPage = PmailPage(driver)
    SharePage = SharePage(driver)
    driver.get(config.Url.HOME)
    flash = FlashSelenium(driver, "pdfForms")

def test_flash(self):
    print "My flash test starts"
    Ui.wait_for_element(link.W9FormNodes.FILL_ONLINE_BIG, "BIG FILL ONLINE BUTTON!").click()
    time.sleep(10)
    print "sleep is over"
    print flash
    flash.call("close")
```

So here I start my tests on selenium grid, open my link, than click BIG button and my flash editor opens. And there I gave to FlashSelenium my driver and id of flash frame.

```
<div id="flash-content" style="position:relative; z-index: 0;">
    <object id="pdfForms" width="100%" height="100%" align="middle" bottommargin="0" rightmargin="0" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" codebase="https://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=10,0,0,0" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000">
        <param value="https://MY_TEST_ADDRESS.com/flash/wrapper2.swf?nocache=.20141202.102738" name="movie">
        <param value="sameDomain" name="allowScriptAccess">
        <param value="high" name="quality">
        <param value="#ffffff" name="bgcolor">
        <param value="type=editor&target_swf=https://MY_TEST_ADDRESS.com/flash/editor2.swf?ver=.20141208.074208&login_hash=T6k3fUBSgtqv1IDd4aBp&viewer_id=10970112&project_id=20077105&lang=en&path=https://MY_TEST_ADDRESS.com/flash/data&log_id=46042" name="FlashVars">
        <embed width="100%" height="100%" align="middle" pluginspage="https://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" flashvars="type=editor&target_swf=https://MY_TEST_ADDRESS.com/flash/editor2.swf?ver=.20141208.074208&login_hash=T6k3fUBSgtqv1IDd4aBp&viewer_id=10970112&project_id=20077105&lang=en&path=https://MY_TEST_ADDRESS.com/flash/data&log_id=46042" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" name="pdfForms" bottommargin="0" rightmargin="0" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" quality="high" src="https://MY_TEST_ADDRESS.com/flash/wrapper2.swf?nocache=.20141202.102738">
```

Here is what i get:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mkurganskiy/Documents/Python/PDFfiller_Tests/tests/teeeeest.py", line 55, in test_flash
    flash.call("close")
  File "/Users/mkurganskiy/Documents/Python/PDFfiller_Tests/com/thoughtworks/selenium/FlashSelenium.py", line 43, in call
    self.flashJSStringPrefix = self.checkBrowserAndReturnJSPrefix()
  File "/Users/mkurganskiy/Documents/Python/PDFfiller_Tests/com/thoughtworks/selenium/FlashSelenium.py", line 133, in checkBrowserAndReturnJSPrefix
    appName = self.seleniumObj.get_eval("navigator.userAgent")
  AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'get_eval'
```

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794087/running-javascript-in-selenium-using-python

Comment: I saw it. but get_eval used in some of FlashSelenium methods, I already try to change it to execute_script and it doesn't help. Maybe I need to change it in some specific way? I nedd to change flash.call("close") to driver.execute_script(what should be here?)