# Getting innertext value using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to get some data from https://www.facebook.com/public/nitin-solanki page. I can get all values apart from

`Studied at`
`Lives in`
`From`

These three label. Value for this label I could get using

```
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/public/nitin-solanki")         
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "mbm")))
    for s in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.mbm.detailedsearch_result'):
        result = {}
        v =  s.find_element_by_css_selector('.fsm.fwn.fcg')
        x = v.find_elements_by_class_name('fbProfileBylineLabel')
        for y in x:
        #print y.text #this should give me label like lives in, studied at but does not
            z = y.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
            for a in z:
                print a.text #I want to get label for this value along with it
```

What i want to do is create dictionary

```
{'Studied_at' : 'Gujarat University', 'Lives_in': 'Ahmedabad, India', 'From' : 'Ahmedabad, India'}
```

for these three values.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the nodevalue of the element using Javascript [Childnodes](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_childnodes.asp) property

```
//try in browser console
    document.getElementsByClassName("fbProfileBylineLabel")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;//Studied at

    document.getElementsByClassName("fbProfileBylineLabel")[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;//Lives in

    document.getElementsByClassName("fbProfileBylineLabel")[2].childNodes[0].nodeValue;//From
```

**pseudocode**

```
v =  s.find_element_by_css_selector('.fsm.fwn.fcg')
        x = v.find_elements_by_class_name('fbProfileBylineLabel')
        for y in x:
            //Example in java(sry not to familiar with python)
           JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
         String s= (String)js.executeScript("return arguments[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;",x);

            z = y.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
```

Hope this helps you.Kindly get back if you have any doubts

Comment: will there be JS executor in python too?

Comment: yes it is there...refer the links  http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html                                                            http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794087/running-javascript-in-selenium-using-python

Comment: thanks, I tried in these way, `        #print x.executeScript("return arguments[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;");
        print driver.executeScript("return arguments[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;",x)` none of them print any thing, need to explore more

Comment: @niper You cannot use x.executescript executescript executes JavaScript in the context of current window and acts on driver instance.you should pass the webelement as an argument like print driver_instance.executeScript("return arguments[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;",x);