# Selenium in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

```
</form></table>
   <br>
     <table><tr><th>Login With Password:
        <tr><td class=w><form method=POST action="/do_login">
           User Name: <input name="name" type="text">
           &nbsp; Password: <input name="password" type="password">
           <input type="submit" value="Login">
           <input name="redirect" type="hidden" value="">
</form></table>
```

I would like to also post the hidden field doing log in, and selenium only allows me to use the `send_key` function with only field that are enabled and displayed.

Without posting the `input hidden value` doing log in, it won't log in, I was able to do it with `requests` module with the `data` parameter in the `request.post()` function, but Id like to it with selenium.

Comment: You want to modify the field before POSTing it? It will be a part of your request no matter what.

Comment: You could execute JavaScript that would fill in the hidden field value: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794087/running-javascript-in-selenium-using-python

Comment: no i dont want to try modifying it...i only want to add to the data being sent when logging it...when sending that hidden value with the username and password..the log in wont be accepted....