# How to click an element which is loaded through Ajax through webdriver within Chrome

Tags: ajax, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

Browser     : Chrome V65

ChromeDriver: chromedriver.exe 2.37

Error occurs while webdriver trying to click an element. The below is my click():

```
def click(self):
    try:
        self.wait_for().visible()
        self._selenium_context().click()
    except Exception as e:
        raise NoSuchElementException

def visible(self):
    '''
    Check if the element is visible.
    :return:  True or exception.
    '''
    return Utils.wait_for(self.web_element.visible, self.interval, self.timeout)
```

I had already waited for element visible and then clicked. But exception was thrown saying 'Other element would receive the click' as below:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <div class="learn-wrap" ng-click="changeTab(2)" ng-class="internal.tab == 2?'learn-selected':''">...</div> is not clickable at point (1026, 89). Other element would receive the click: <div class="loading-data ng-scope ng-animate ng-leave ng-leave-active" ng-if="internal.isAjaxing" data-ng-animate="2" style="">...</div>
```

Error occurs even if I add statement to wait ajax loading finished to click the element:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'learn') and (contains(@ng-if, '!internal.isAjaxing'))]")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH , element_xpath).click()
```

This happens on Chrome frequently, maybe 4 in 5 times failure. It doesn't work!

Now, I have to use sleep to wait element to be clickable instead.

Can anybody help? Thanks.

Comment: You can use javascript executor please ref this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794087/running-javascript-in-selenium-using-python\

Comment: Thanks. action_chains works for me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use action class to click element,

Syntax:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement("Your Element").click().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned *Ajax Calls* are involved and you *are using sleep to wait for the element to be clickable*, instead of that you need to use *WebDriverWait* for the element to be clickable as follows :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC    

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'learn') and (contains(@ng-if, '!internal.isAjaxing'))]"))).click()
```