# ContextClick options are not working in Selenium 3.0

Tags: selenium-webdriver

#### Problem Statement

I am using Selenium 3.14, Mac OS and Chrome version 71.0.3578.98 for my automation.

I tried this simple way: go to www.google.com and then right click on Gmail link and select on "open link in new window", but it's not happening :(

I have tried 2 options, both are not working, meaning the first option is not getting selected

I tried with the Robot class, but am unable to click "open link in new window" -- the Action Class is not working as expected.

#### Option-1

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.linkText("Gmail"));    
Point p = element.getLocation();
int x = p.getX();
int y = p.getY();
System.out.println(x+":"+y);
Robot r=new Robot();
r.mouseMove(1115, 19);
r.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK);
r.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

#### Option-2

```
Actions action= new Actions(driver);
action.contextClick(element)
    .sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
    .sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)
    .perform();
```

Comment: Please try with https://stackoverflow.com/a/50019382/9405154

Comment: nope, this wont work as this opens in same window , it should open link in new tab