# Selenium, Python- Clicking behind an element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to **click a log in button with selenium** (chrome driver, --headless). The **problem is** that there is a **element in front of** the **log in button**. Is there a way to click the button even if an element is in the way?

My Python script looks something like this:

```
pirkciau_driver=webdriver.Chrome(crm_path, chrome_options=options)
pirkciau_driver.get(login_url)
elem = pirkciau_driver.find_element_by_id("email")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys(x['pirkciau']['username'])
elem = pirkciau_driver.find_element_by_id("passwd")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys(x['pirkciau']['password'])
elem = pirkciau_driver.find_element_by_id("SubmitLogin")
elem.click()
```

Comment: What *"element in front of the log in button"* should mean? Another element is overlapping target button? Do you get an exception?

Comment: Selenium is intended to emulate user behaviour. How would a user click an element that is obscured by another? Why do you need to click that element, and how does a real user handle this case when doing it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `JavaScript Click` as below :

```
pirkciau_driver=webdriver.Chrome(crm_path, chrome_options=options)
pirkciau_driver.get(login_url)
elem = pirkciau_driver.find_element_by_id("email")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys(x['pirkciau']['username'])
elem = pirkciau_driver.find_element_by_id("passwd")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys(x['pirkciau']['password'])
elem = pirkciau_driver.find_element_by_id("SubmitLogin")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem);
```

Comment: Be aware that by using JS to click an element obscured by another element, you aren't testing a real user scenario. No user can click an element under another element. Best practice is to close or otherwise remove the blocking element before clicking the desired element. If something is in the way, how would a user dismiss the covering element?

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
pirkciau_driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', elem)
```

to click button that's currently overlapped by another element, but it won't simulate the real user-like behavior... If you're testing something, it's better to wait until element that receives click instead of LogIn button becomes invisible with [ExplicitWait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) and `until_not(EC.visibility_of_element_located())` or `until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located())`

Comment: Nice to learn a new thing `until_not`. Is this a newly released approach @sir Andersson?.

Comment: No. It's an old approach. I'm quite sure that I've already used it 2-3 years ago...

Comment: the only solution so far

Answer (score 1):

Few ways to do that:

- Execute JavaScript:
  [Running javascript in Selenium using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794087/running-javascript-in-selenium-using-python)
- Maybe you can login using keyboard(sending enter key)?
  `elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)`
- Try clicking on other element so modal is removed and can click on the button you need.