# How to modify/send keys to a google doc with selenium on python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, google-docs

I can't find out how to modify/send keys to a new blank google doc with selenium, both with the content and the title. I suspect it may have something to do with frames, however they appear empty when I inspect the html. Any suggestions?

```
content = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body')
content.send_keys('test')

actions.send_keys('test')
actions.perform()

title= browser.find_element_by_class_name('docs-title-input')
title.send_keys('Title')
```

I already tried following this question [How to send keys in Google Document using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52766626/how-to-send-keys-in-google-document-using-selenium) but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Can you share the exact URL you are working on ?

Comment: @cruisepandey It is just a blank new google doc document