# Getting the Length of a Video in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am building a bot in Python Selenium which can enroll in Free Highest rated courses on Udemy. I also want the bot to play videos for me and when the video gets finished, it can then move on to the next video. Previously i searched on Google and found some of the Answers of how to get a video length of a video file but these are not working on Udemy Course Video..

What i actually want is to get the total length of a video in seconds or minutes while the bot will continuously keep track of the time and when the played time becomes equal to the total length of a video, it can then move on to the next video...Below is the code that i am using which will only Log in to the account and Enroll in one of the Free Searched Course on Udemy.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

email='huaaddty8339@gmail.com'
password='kulningkswoymama7'

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.udemy.com')
time.sleep(25)
browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[6]').click()
time.sleep(9)

browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email--1"]').send_keys(email)
time.sleep(4)

browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="id_password"]').send_keys(password)
time.sleep(2)

browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="submit-id-submit"]').click()
time.sleep(16)

browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="header-search-field"]').send_keys("Python")
time.sleep(15)

WebDriverWait(browser,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[.//span[text()='All 
Filters']]"))).click()


time.sleep(5)
WebDriverWait(browser,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//label[@title and 
.//span/span[text()='Free']]"))).click()
time.sleep(5)

browser.execute_script("window.open('');") 
time.sleep(5)
browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[1])
time.sleep(5)
browser.get("https://www.udemy.com/course/kypython-101/")
time.sleep(30)
try:

 browser.find_element_by_xpath("//html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/button").click()
 time.sleep(3)

except:
 WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[5]/div/div/div/button"))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1. Parse id of the video tag that holds required video
2. Execute javascript code within a page like `document.getElementById('playerId__4399364_html5_api').duration` which will return duration in seconds. Do not forget to change id to one relevant to your case.

**P.S.** - You can learn more about JS execution here: [Running javascript in Selenium using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794087/running-javascript-in-selenium-using-python/7794217)

**P.P.S.** - Here you can find [more properties of `video`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp) which migh help you in your tasks.