# selenium open browser console and paste some javascript code using python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a javascript which I want to put in console when page loaded but i am unable to open console using selenium in python I can access devtoos using this `--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs` but not able to open console.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import os
import time
from urllib.parse import quote_plus

driverPath = "chromedriver.exe"
dataPath = "whatsapp-assistant-bot-master/Data"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=" + dataPath)
options.add_argument("--auto-open-console-for-tabs=" + dataPath)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=driverPath)

driver.get('http://google.com')
print('Please Scan the QR Code and press enter')

 driver.find_element_by_id("gsr").send_keys(Keys.F12)



input()
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered here, you don't have to open the console, you can run your js code through selenium

[Running javascript in Selenium using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7794217/8692977)