# selenium how to run a javascript function

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I have this on a website

```
div class="accept"  onclick="javascript:ClosePopup(true);" ...
```

If I run "ClosePopup(true)" in the browser console, the button works and closes the popup.

In selenium, I think something like driver.executeScript(ClosePopup(true))
  but that is not the correct way.
Please advice how to click the button once that is a popup that shows up only sometimes and do not have id, only a class but the class has 4 or more buttons inside.

I am using selenium with python 3.8.

Comment: Have you read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/29273838/11865571

Comment: Why are you trying to close the popup with javascript instead of just using `.click()` on the element? This is also impossible to answer without seeing all of your page HTML.

Comment: I think you need to use `execute_script` instead of `executeScript`.

Comment: found it,  it's driver.execute_script("javascript:ClosePopup(true);")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, there are a few components and methods to executing Javascript:

1. Find the element you want to execute script on
2. Pass in the element as a Javascript argument

This translates to:

```
# 1. find element
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='accept']")

# 2. execute script
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

The Javascript function is reading in `element` as a parameter and performing `.click()` on the element. You do not *have* to pass in a WebElement, and you can use something like `document.getElementById()` in the Javascript function itself:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('id').click();")
```

Given the HTML for the `div` element you have provided, I don't think you actually need to use Javascript at all though. You should just be able to use:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='accept']").click()
```