# Why Selenium Python Select Returns Blank Text When Option Text Exists

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium

I have a `select` that looks like this:

```
<select data-origvalue="" multiple="multiple" name="project_9999" id="project_9999" style="display: none;">
<option value="1">Option1</option>
<option value="2">Option2</option>
</select>
```

I am trying to view the options like this...

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('project_9999'))
print([o.text for o in select.options])
```

...which results in:

```
['','']
```

Why is the text of each option not appearing in the list? How would I select one of the options without the options being fully visible?

Comment: I don't see an element named `project_template_1511`.

Comment: if you use `select = ...` second time then you remove previous value. Did you use `print(select)` after each `select = ...` ?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by _... which results in:_ ?  All you've done is find an element and initialize a `Select` object from it; there is no code that would print out the options of that Select object.

Comment: better create minimal working code with real url. And then we can run it and test what can be problem.

Comment: very sorry - I pasted the wrong line of code. updated now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the child elements of `project_9999`, not the parent `select` element. You can do that like so

```py
options = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'project_9999')
for option in options.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'option'):
    print(option.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

Returns

```
Option1
Option2
```

You'll probably want to add in some error handling if the element doesn't exist etc.

Comment: how would I actually select one of the options using this method?

Comment: Because your element is `display: none`, I think you'll have to select it using [Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29273838/11916773). You can either set the `display` to shown or manually select your option.