# BeautifulSoup is not parsing entire html

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to make crawling logic for Google Patents with BeautifulSoup in Python.

But some problems are happened for parsing html to read the page info.

I used some modules for this

- Requests
- BeautifulSoup(bs4)
- Selenium

But when I printed the result of bs4, I realized it is not reading entire html.
I need help to solve this problem.
Here is the partial sentences of my code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_driver_path = 'D:/Drivers/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=chrome_driver_path)

URL = 'https://patents.google.com/?q=engine&oq=engine'
driver.get(URL)
html = driver.page_source

gp_soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(gp_soup)  #it not prints entire html of the URL
pagination = gp_soup.find('div', {'id': 'pagingAndInfo'})

print(pagination)  # it prints 'none'
```

Comment: You say it isnt printing entire content and then in the code it says it prints `None`?

Comment: have you looked at the contents of the html variable to see if the item you are looking for is present?

Comment: @DirtyBit the result of  'print(gp_soup)' is showing html but it is not entire of it. So when I was finding 'pagingAndInfo', it prints 'none'

Comment: Yes, it's because if you do a `view-source` on your browser you would see that much of the content is being sent by a `script` - so, your `print(gp_soup)` is showing the underlying code - but, that's not matching with the view you see when you open up the link!

Comment: @LhasaDad Yes. I read all html of website by using F12 key to compare with printed one. But the printed one was containing only partial contents.

Comment: @ParthaMandal Thank you. then how to get all of the contents from script?

Comment: @JasonK : check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/a/29273838/13070032
This should point you in the right direction!

Comment: @ParthaMandal It was helpful. But I realized the Selenium is not crawling folded html area in my code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They provide the results data through `XHR`, why not access that:
Try this:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'authority': 'patents.google.com',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="83"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'x-client-data': 'CJC2yQEIprbJAQjEtskBCKmdygEI/7zKARibvsoB',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'referer': 'https://patents.google.com/?q=engine&oq=engine',
    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'cookie': 'CONSENT=YES+PK.en+201911; HSID=A2sPirRiegxhfvmpY; SSID=A9_w65uykVnHiwUDa; APISID=Jdu8dOOrCs0rn7b8/AXynv0eG8EqtYgdia; SAPISID=TEilNNPIbvz8TpL9/AnfZcRvwbgch0qHH7; __Secure-3PAPISID=TEilNNPIbvz8TpL9/AnfZcRvwbgch0qHH7; __Secure-HSID=A2sPirRiegxhfvmpY; __Secure-SSID=A9_w65uykVnHiwUDa; __Secure-APISID=Jdu8dOOrCs0rn7b8/AXynv0eG8EqtYgdia; __Secure-3PSIDCC=AJi4QfFpt093qgz73bJdPnjtKSCJYd5AWKpm4QsbYq90j87k3oeMopn3_yqm-LCcapmc2RUtoMk; SID=xwce5HYf8fUVXKzMwGIFJE-cMdC-I_wtCe4H-Ts0IDVDkR46w4RTr7SB963THvwklqInDg.; __Secure-3PSID=xwce5HYf8fUVXKzMwGIFJE-cMdC-I_wtCe4H-Ts0IDVDkR46Jdg8q-UcCeDr1M9M-E8HZA.; ANID=AHWqTUmEDbOop_zvr8CHCsm69epk8jE3y0_qH4mvs3L9II6_8dKlDOsE8wLTcaTR; 1P_JAR=2020-06-28-06; NID=204=JujF91JNPL6fhoVJB7vJaFOg_eO4KRQWdZ8f-PLWA3BwnKl1ky0s9yA95CQiykb5_uNub-MuChOKpQYWfKd3R5dNGYahg5MahGAC6qHAvCWZD8QTl5YB_3BUA6SxWFFvjxxJIgUMtOMf2p_CY9fyJ1txSuw4ZO-C6epdeCqbXexdL5cQ60Bnf4YeGGEejoDdO0WXzyr-0TKVPKJj_xlw1EB3VJd3DgJFx6cMn3ZSgs_EbpkYMdMygPhby7Y; _ga=GA1.3.210705560.1593329477; _gid=GA1.3.306543010.1593329477; _gat=1; SIDCC=AJi4QfHRNNa2iz0vlb2X3eYLJZjgTVItm2aKjXGJaPC0eeRQHCSQJPchpLDL_oRouIE_iZG4jLY',
}

params = (
    ('url', 'q=engine&oq=engine'),
    ('exp', ''),
)

response = requests.get('https://patents.google.com/xhr/query', headers=headers, params=params).json()
print(response)
```

Output:

```
{'results': {'total_num_results': 85568, 'total_num_pages': 30, 'many_results': False, 'num_page': 0, 'cluster': [{'result': [{'rank': 0, 'patent': {'title': ' Control system for an internal combustion <b>engine</b>', 'snippet': ' Control system for an internal combustion <b>engine</b> ( 3 ) calculating a most fuel efficient torque (TRQBSFCB) that minimizes a fuel consumption ratio (BSFC) and the <b>engine</b> ( 3 ) based on the most fuel-efficient torque (TRQBSFCB), comprising: an air-fuel ratio control means for controlling the air-fuel &hellip;', 'priority_date': '2012-09-25', 'filing_date': '2013-09-20', 'grant_date': '2016-01-14', 'publication_date': '2016-01-14', 'inventor': 'Masaki Ueno', 'assignee': 'Honda Motor Co., Ltd.', 'publication_number': 'DE102013218969B4', 'language': 'en', 'thumbnail': '86/d7/d0/bd4fa307298a6b/DE102013218969B4_0002.png', 'pdf': '', 'figures': [{'thumbnail': '4b/e7/7f/7f6e0cd7f93294/DE102013218969B4_0002.png', 'full': '8b/53/fb/16bbbb5e3df313/DE102013218969B4_0002.png'}, {'thumbnail': '61/6f/b7/f2022993ab5ec6/DE102013218969B4_0003.png', 'full': '88/b0/6f/124e2fabd3dda5/DE102013218969B4_0003.png'}, {'thumbnail': '66/cc/85/b119ed5783693c/DE102013218969B4_0004.png', 'full': 'f6/20/b7/069218b9d84add/DE102013218969B4_0004.png'}, {'thumbnail': 'e4/4b/85/53e3166adc8648/DE102013218969B4_0005.png', 'full': 'ac/e8/6f/45329df82b891d/DE102013218969B4_0005.png'}, {'thumbnail': '50/64/e7/dea5bf673dd14b/DE102013218969B4_0006.png', 'full': '75/bc/59/5b8e87d0194f18/DE102013218969B4_0006.png'}, {'thumbnail': '0b/aa/42/8ce456cb47328b/DE102013218969B4_0007.png', 'full': '64/b6/9f/e94ecde4d434e9/DE102013218969B4_0007.png'}, {'thumbnail': 'f2/a8/c2/71b063f076b674/DE102013218969B4_0008.png', 'full': '90/e8/0b/60862e91b4d83f/DE102013218969B4_0008.png'}, {'thumbnail': '60/c3/aa/fd862145fb1c3f/DE102013218969B4_0009.png', 'full': 'b6/17/9c/409f41c67650c6/DE102013218969B4_0009.png'}, {'thumbnail': 'f0/14/d7/5be1f4967a0f58/DE102013218969B4_0010.png', 'full': '74/57/f4/cb1132ae483a91/DE102013218969B4_0010.png'}, {'thumbnail': 'c6/2c/f8/40e7746201e05d/DE102013218969B4_0011.png', 'full': '69/0b/03/33a2d5d98c1c98/DE102013218969B4_0011.png'}, {'thumbnail': '80/1b/4b/fe76b227f528d7/DE102013218969B4_0012.png', 'full': '59/80/e4/969c17b467bbce/DE102013218969B4_0012.png'}, {'thumbnail': 'cc/1d/58/e849a6c54910a5/DE102013218969B4_0013.png', 'full': '55/b5/4c/0b1111f4d83ba7/DE102013218969B4_0013.png'}, {'thumbnail': 'c6/16/8f/39b3f1fffcdaa0/DE102013218969B4_0014.png', 'full': 'de/e1/37/35e70bb3865d65/DE102013218969B4_0014.png'}, {'thumbnail': '9a/6d/31/9f24cddb1b98a7/DE102013218969B4_0015.png', 'full': '9a/2d/77/522e47cc65cf0f/DE102013218969B4_0015.png'}, {'thumbnail': '68/7e/e2/f7ff720a8a4000/DE102013218969B4_0016.png', 'full': '47/40/74/7156e4d0f4fd30/DE102013218969B4_0016.png'}, {'thumbnail': '9d/bc/2c/5939cba521683d/DE102013218969B4_0017.png', 'full': '66/57/b9/2a3f02ce5867e9/DE102013218969B4_0017.png'}], 'family_metadata': {'aggregated': {'country_status': [{'country_code': 'US', 'best_patent_stage': {'state': 'ACTIVE'}}, {'country_code': 'JP', 'best_patent_stage': {'state': 'ACTIVE'}}, {'country_code': 'DE', 'best_patent_stage': {'state': 'ACTIVE'}}]}}}, 'is_similar_document': False, 'entity_matches': {'additional': 0}}, {'rank': 1, 'patent': {'title': ' Internal combustion <b>engine</b> and method of operating same', 'snippet': ' 16. A method for maximizing a fuel efficiency of an <b>engine</b> comprising the steps of: providing an <b>engine</b> including an <b>engine</b> block having a cylinder bank including a plurality of cylinder bores formed therein, a piston reciprocatingly disposed in each of the cylinder bores, a crankshaft rotatably &hellip;', 'priority_date': '2009-05-15', 'filing_date': '2013-11-18', 'grant_date': '2015-03-31', 'publication_date': '2015-03-31', 'inventor': 'Douglas A. Pelmear', 'assignee': 'Douglas A. Pelmear', 'publication_number': 'US8991356B2', 'language': 'en', 'thumbnail': '2d/30/95/75f9c42f2bbe8d/US08991356-20150331-D00000.png', 'pdf': 'f0/f9/a6/6467a8f27a59cc/US8991356.pdf', 'figures': [{'thumbnail': 'b7/68/26/cf767150e0658e/US08991356-20150331-D00000.png', 'full': '3a/5c/61/1e7c3169ce95fd/US08991356-20150331-D00000.png'}, {'thumbnail': '3c/9a/cb/d9815d0c3c2491/US08991356-20150331-D00001.png', 'full': '53/5e/a5/b2dcfd1cce0ad7/US08991356-20150331-D00001.png'}, {'thumbnail': '5f/2d/97/9e7670cd24d243/US08991356-20150331-D00002.png', 'full': '14/49/8a/bf7e6f007768d0/US08991356-20150331-D00002.png'}, {'thumbnail': '6c/34/e8/165296fc37f165/US08991356-20150331-D00003.png', 'full': 'a3/0f/11/5135191c0816de/US08991356-20150331-D00003.png'}, {'thumbnail': 'c5/f0/21/d808fe20e26a84/US08991356-20150331-D00004.png', 'full': 'f3/92/18/c2c02aed002d66/US08991356-20150331-D00004.png'}, {'thumbnail': '0f/fb/ae/1ed28fcfd36c33/US08991356-20150331-D00005.png', 'full': 'a3/b2/c9/e94b89237e89b3/US08991356-20150331-D00005.png'}, {'thumbnail': '9d/00/fa/fc4a2e896c6527/US08991356-20150331-D00006.png', 'full': '74/9c/5f/2147a180eb0057/US08991356-20150331-D00006.png'}, {'thumbnail': '66/a9/8c/f04776fd198a4d/US08991356-20150331-D00007.png', 'full': 'de/7f/e1/ca4910497617dc/US08991356-20150331-D00007.png'}, {'thumbnail': '35/1d/78/018ed091b63a2c/US08991356-20150331-D00008.png', 'full': 'df/49/17/2acf7db7cbe5ab/US08991356-20150331-D00008.png'}], 'family_metadata': {'aggregated': {'country_status': [{'country_code': 'WO', 'best_patent_stage': {'state': 'ACTIVE'}}, {'country_code': 'EP', 'best_patent_stage': {'state': 'ACTIVE'}}, {'country_code': 'US', 'best_patent_stage': {'state': 'ACTIVE'}}, {'country_code': 'CN', 'best_patent_stage': {'state': 'ACTIVE'}}, {'country_code': 'CA', 'best_patent_stage': {'state': 'ACTIVE'}}, {'country_code': 'ES', 'best_patent_stage': {'state': 'ACTIVE'}}]}}}, 'is_similar_document': False, 'entity_matches': {'additional': 0}}, {'rank': 2, 'patent': {'title': ' Fuel injection control apparatus for <b>engine</b>', 'snippet': ' What is claimed is: 1. A fuel injection control apparatus for an <b>engine</b> in which fuel is injected into a cylinder a plurality of times to cause a plurality of combustions, comprising: a controller for controlling a time interval of performing a plurality of fuel injections so that, for each of the &hellip;', 'priority_date': '2015-05-18', 'filing_date': '2016-05-16', 'grant_date': '2018-07-17', 'publication_date': '2018-07-17', 'inventor': 'Naotoshi Shirahashi', 'assignee': 'Mazda Motor Corporation', 'publication_number': 'US10024250B2', 'language': 'en', 'thumbnail': '37/f5/11/5b90c652f998f5/US10024250-20180717-D00000.png', 'pdf': '5e/a9/c3/bb11ff6bc2db6f/US10024250.pdf', 'figures': [{'thumbnail': '18/8d/3c/fd84d128c6bb61/US10024250-20180717-D00000.png', 'full': '46/28/cf/363a5d4e1344f5/US10024250-20180717-D00000.png'}, {'thumbnail': '9a/a8/0c/3dd04726289f20/US10024250-20180717-D00001.png', 'full': 'b1/0b/be/ef9e3a503b796d/US10024250-20180717-D00001.png'}, {'thumbnail': 'ac/25/22/653e45df2d5bd4/US10024250-20180717-D00002.png', 'full': 'ab/43/1e/befc21058187cd/US10024250-20180717-D00002.png'}, {'thumbnail': '1b/0a/a9/bb8b903547f05e/US10024250-20180717-D00003.png', 'full': '41/25/6b/f990d73da9a3b9/US10024250-20180717-D00003.png'}, {'thumbnail': 'e6/18/95/d9daf1e9763499/US10024250-20180717-D00004.png', 'full': '0a/80/fb/002bf82c94bc1c/US10024250-20180717-D00004.png'}, {'thumbnail': '25/ed/36/1f20b2e2ea990f/US10024250-20180717-D00005.png', 'full': 'c5/43/4d/58bdd98f6b59c8/US10024250-20180717-D00005.png'}, {'thumbnail': 'a3/a0/3c/134e904c0fc7f2/US10024250-20180717-D00006.png', 'full': '63/1b/0e/0bf2f83086d931/US10024250-20180717-D00006.png'}, {'thumbnail': 'a3/ac/2e/c22dee363138e7/US10024250-20180717-D00007.png', 'full': '92/f0/94/45cb057b0d85f9/US10024250-20180717-D00007.png'}, {'thumbnail': '8e/8b/4b/75ae2f0f2fcd21/US10024250-20180717-D00008.png', 'full': '4e/16/12/7a39646d188896/US10024250-20180717-D00008.png'}, {'thumbnail': 'c4/16/f8/93891b89d540dc/US10024250-20180717-D00009.png', 'full': '88/a2/46/8ff96b168798ae/US10024250-20180717-D00009.png'}, {'thumbnail': 'b1/b1/f7/c815d032be6312/US10024250-20180717-D00010.png', 'full': '14/f8/7b/87391a05ffa5b6/US10024250-20180717-D00010.png'}, {'thumbnail': '33/8b/35/0e43f164f5f40d/US10024250-20180717-D00011.png', 'full': '17/e5/f3/03cfdde368fc94/US10024250-20180717-D00011.png'}, {'thumbnail': 'e3/17/97/7d721ec9e326da/US10024250-20180717-D00012.png', 'full': '1e/1c/0d/ff7013ff183220/US10024250-20180717-D00012.png'}, {'thumbnail': '01/6d/cb/f2c122384615dd/US10024250-20180717-D00013.png', 'full': 'dc/3f/4a/53f64945d73730/US10024250-20180717-D00013.png'}], 'family_metadata': {'aggregated': {'country_status': [{'country_code': 'US', 'best_patent_stage': {'state': 'ACTIVE'}}, {'country_code': 'JP', 'best_patent_stage': {'state': 'ACTIVE'}}, {'country_code': 'DE', 'best_patent_stage': {'state': 'ACTIVE'}}]}}}, 'is_similar_document': False, 'entity_matches': {'additional': 0}}, {'rank': 3, 'patent': {'title': ' Firing fraction management in skip fire <b>engine</b> control', 'snippet': ' 9. A skip fire <b>engine</b> controller as recited in claim 1 wherein each entry in the lookup table further includes a second field arranged to store a value indicative of a second desired operational parameter. 10. An <b>engine</b> controller that includes a skip fire <b>engine</b> controller as recited in claim 1', 'priority_date': '2010-01-11', 'filing_date': '2013-08-09', 'grant_date': '2017-05-16', 'publication_date': '2017-05-16', 'inventor': 'Mohammad R. Pirjaberi', 'assignee': 'Tula Technology, Inc.', 'publication_number': 'US9650971B2', 'language': 'en', 'thumbnail': 'df/ce/f2/0967e72af074b1/US09650971-20170516-D00000.png', 'pdf': '97/9c/a0/c7a34fa8e9241e/US9650971.pdf', 'figures': [{'thumbnail': '46/df/09/e3edfb87d6f368/US09650971-20170516-D00000.png', 'full': '8c/6b/97/927c06dd15d43c/US09650971-20170516-D00000.png'}, {'thumbnail': 'ac/c5/d7/f592a3ef1e7a95/US09650971-20170516-D00001.png', 'full': '5b/93/ae/bb6f1f4933154b/US09650971-20170516-D00001.png'}, {'thumbnail': '5c/68/2a/f2af476400d23b/US09650971-20170516-D00002.png', 'full': '85/02/82/2969b738085368/US09650971-20170516-D00002.png'}, {'thumbnail': '98/c1/31/e54625f03835b8/US09650971-20170516-D00003.png', 'full': '3f/65/43/fe3a5385927ae9/US09650971-20170516-D00003.png'}, {'thumbnail': '34/a5/ed/36dffe130562d6/US09650971-20170516-D00004.png', 'full': '8f/db/71/8d035177add6ed/US09650971-20170516-D00004.png'}, {'thumbnail': '19/fa/52/210febbf7f0287/US09650971-20170516-D00005.png', 'full': 'ad/ae/5a/bd7252457998de/US09650971-20170516-D00005.png'}, {'thumbnail': '47/9d/e2/e01dab117e9f0e/US09650971-20170516-D00006.png', 'full': 'c3/d3/cc/47b1cb9f78e13e/US09650971-20170516-D00006.png'}, {'thumbnail': '17/22/4b/7fc5913abafbca/US09650971-20170516-D00007.png', 'full': '80/12/40/f7a074ae4e4228/US09650971-20170516-D00007.png'}, {'thumbnail': '76/3d/ff/6b1b10aef6116b/US09650971-20170516-D00008.png', 'full': '6d/49/43/e2a93d74533b2c/US09650971-20170516-D00008.png'}], 'family_metadata': {'aggregated': {'country_status': [{'country_code': 'US', 'best_patent_stage': {'state': 'ACTIVE'}}]}}}, 'is_similar_document': False, 'entity_matches': {'additional': 0}}, {'rank': 4, 'patent': {'title': ' Method and system for <b>engine</b> control', 'snippet': ' while propelling a hybrid vehicle via only <b>motor</b> torque, rotating an <b>engine</b> unfueled via the <b>motor</b> torque at lower than <b>engine</b> cranking speed while operating an exhaust heater coupled to an exhaust catalyst and while holding an EGR valve open and an upstream intake throttle closed to recirculate &hellip;', 'priority_date': '2014-04-04', 'filing_date': '2014-04-04', 'grant_date': '2017-09-12', 'publication_date': '2017-09-12', 'inventor': 'Joseph Norman Ulrey', 'assignee': 'Ford Global Technologies, Llc', 'publication_number': 'US9759135B2', 'language': 'en', 'thumbnail': '9d/48/ca/55238fcb6d74ef/US09759135-20170912-D00000.png', 'pdf': '8a/83/bf/d82089917f8c4f/US9759135.pdf', 'figures': [{'thumbnail': 'e2/74/89/86f93f3b7963e0/US09759135-20170912-D00000.png', 'full': 'af/e9/bd/edb2e796cb4ed3/US09759135-20170912-D00000.png'}, {'thumbnail': 'cb/0a/b9/f830ee520569cd/US09759135-20170912-D00001.png', 'full': 'bd/74/9d/2449309ccbd5c1/US09759135-20170912-D00001.png'}, {'thumbnail': '7a/e5/ee/dbf52832cbbc0d/US09759135-20170912-D00002.png', 'full': '0e/99/ca/b3f27b6f717364/US09759135-20170912-D00002.png'}, {'thumbnail': '28/b5/13/e326085b6c1fa7/US09759135-20170912-D00003.png', 'full': 'd4/f6/23/265d6e5fd70ad3/US09759135-20170912-D00003.png'}, {'thumbnail': '43/af/55/c6be548b806cc2/US09759135-20170912-D00004.png', 'full': 'f2/bc/a8/5aeaa87b0562fc/US09759135-20170912-D00004.png'}, {'thumbnail': '5f/8b/e7/a704863d2b3e8b/US09759135-20170912-D00005.png', 'full': 'e8/f3/32/65b73e722f5d2d/US09759135-20170912-D00005.png'}, {'thumbnail': 'c1/b6/9f/bac1b2abcb6a9c/US09759135-20170912-D00006.png', 'full': 'f9/a8/28/2718d18f31608f/US09759135-20170912-D00006.png'}, {'thumbnail': '4b/9c/2b/ad36fb19a67780/US09759135-20170912-D00007.png', 'full': '71/8f/ce/320bc6937314a8/US09759135-20170912-D00007.png'}, {'thumbnail': 'ac/bc/ff/018619099eec8c/US09759135-20170912-D00008.png', 'full': 'ec/e4/40/cc1fb2389bee77/US09759135-20170912-D00008.png'}], 'family_metadata': {'aggregated': {'country_status': [{'country_code': 'US', 'best_patent_stage': {'state': 'ACTIVE'}}, {'country_code': 'CN', 'best_patent_stage': {'state': 'ACTIVE'}}, {'country_code': 'DE', 'best_patent_stage': {'state': 'ACTIVE'}}, {'country_code': 'RU', 'best_patent_stage': {'state': 'ACTIVE'}}]}}}, 'is_similar_document': False, 'entity_matches': {'additional': 0}}, {'rank': 5, 'patent': {'title': ' <b>Engine</b> system', 'snippet': ' Mechanical supercharger, described mechanical supercharger is arranged in the upstream of <b>engine</b> intake manifold and the compressor parallel of described turbosupercharger. 2. <b>engine</b> system according to claim 1, is characterized in that, described the first gas-storing chamber and described the &hellip;', 'priority_date': '2012-08-21', 'filing_date': '2013-08-20', 'grant_date': '2014-03-12', 'publication_date': '2014-03-12', 'inventor': '罗伯特·安德鲁·韦德', 'assignee': '福特环球技术公司', 'publication_number': 'CN203476491U', 'language': 'en', 'thumbnail': '', 'pdf': 'e2/90/1e/36b22c275098e5/CN203476491U.pdf', 'family_metadata': {'aggregated': {'country_status': [{'country_code': 'US', 'best_patent_stage': {'state': 'ACTIVE'}}, {'country_code': 'CN', 'best_patent_stage': {'state': 'ACTIVE'}}, {'country_code': 'DE', 'best_patent_stage': {'state': 'ACTIVE'}}, {'country_code': 'RU', 'best_patent_stage': {'state': 'ACTIVE'}}]}}}, 'is_similar_document': False, 'entity_matches': {'additional': 0}}, {'rank': 6, 'patent': {'title': ' Coordinated <b>engine</b> torque control', 'snippet': ' A control system for an <b>engine</b> includes a target air per cylinder (APC) module, a target area module, and a phaser scheduling module. The target APC module determines a target APC based on a target spark timing, a target intake cam phaser angle, and a target exhaust cam phaser angle. The target &hellip;', 'priority_date': '2012-09-13', 'filing_date': '2012-09-13', 'grant_date': '2015-11-03', 'publication_date': '2015-11-03', 'inventor': 'Michael Livshiz', 'assignee': 'GM Global Technology Operations LLC', 'publication_number': 'US9175628B2', 'language': 'en', 'thumbnail': 'c3/db/7b/a357c0104e7936/US09175628-20151103-D00000.png', 'pdf': 'ba/cf/7f/5be34e712339c4/US9175628.pdf', 'figures': [{'thumbnail': '36/0f/31/c8feebdebcfb2f/US09175628-20151103-D00000.png', 'full': '21/15/5e/ac1d0a70ee8aee/US09175628-20151103-D00000.png'}, {'thumbnail': '65/74/cb/a08db8b9301e3f/US09175628-20151103-D00001.png', 'full': '66/f3/e1/5e9cef82abfc53/US09175628-20151103-D00001.png'}, {'thumbnail': 'a9/dd/8e/e7c0a60f9becca/US09175628-20151103-D00002.png', 'full': '08/b7/20/e57d70580da408/US09175628-20151103-D00002.png'}, {'thumbnail': '7e/99/bb/f39eb2b1e03247/US09175628-20151103-D00003.png', 'full': '18/b6/26/58c21b165cf6dc/US09175628-20151103-D00003.png'}, {'thumbnail': '39/58/5b/bf7063a50c895d/US09175628-20151103-D00004.png', 'full': 'fd/4a/94/1bb5167e747ee4/US09175628-20151103-D00004.png'}], 'family_metadata': {'aggregated': {'country_status': [{'country_code': 'US', 'best_patent_stage': {'state': 'ACTIVE'}}, {'country_code': 'CN', 'best_patent_stage': {'state': 'ACTIVE'}}, {'country_code': 'DE', 'best_patent_stage': {'state': 'ACTIVE'}}]}}}, 'is_similar_document': False, 'entity_matches': {'additional': 0}}, {'rank': 7, 'patent': {'title': ' <b>Engine</b> operation method and <b>engine</b> system', 'snippet': ' a second direct injection nozzle connected to the <b>engine</b> cylinder, and a control system with machine-readable instructions for performing fuel injection into the inlet and direct fuel injection during the first combustion process in the cylinder with a ratio that is lower when the <b>engine</b> is cold &hellip;', 'priority_date': '2012-12-19', 'filing_date': '2013-12-19', 'grant_date': '2017-09-04', 'publication_date': '2017-09-04', 'inventor': 'Гопичандра СУРНИЛЛА', 'assignee': 'Форд Глобал Технолоджис, ЛЛК', 'publication_number': 'RU2629791C2', 'language': 'en', 'thumbnail': '8e/a8/c9/63cac25ebc5a76/00000002.png', 'pdf': 'b8/11/20/d662248679d36d/RU2629791C2.pdf', 'figures': [{'thumbnail': '08/1a/67/40c58cc97a6557/00000002.png', 'full': '6a/64/ee/86f8bf1b37c650/00000002.png'}, {'thumbnail': 'ed/0d/d2/4aee0eb3e13222/00000003.png', 'full': '4b/cd/3f/fa9a8939cc1998/00000003.png'}, {'thumbnail': 'e1/ef/85/1748402459c8b4/00000004.png', 'full': '5c/1f/7a/d6f3a45bba6c5b/00000004.png'}, {'thumbnail': '0a/b5/76/3ab08e0edf609c/00000005.png', 'full': '68/2c/f1/3018e1475b9f1a/00000005.png'}], 'family_metadata': {'aggregated': {'country_status': [{'country_code': 'US', 'best_patent_stage': {'state': 'ACTIVE'}}, {'country_code': 'CN', 'best_patent_stage': {'state': 'ACTIVE'}}, {'country_code': 'DE', 'best_patent_stage': {'state': 'ACTIVE'}}, {'country_code': 'RU', 'best_patent_stage': {'state': 'ACTIVE'}}]}}}, 'is_similar_document': False, 'entity_matches': {'additional': 0}},
```

Comment: I'll try it. Thank you.

Comment: But I wanna ask you one thing, How could you take all html data from XHR shaped page?

Comment: @JasonK Pages now a days are rendered using Javascript, dynamically. So you can't extract the html data straight away. You have to find out manually whether a website provides API or not? Else You do it with Webdriver (Selenium etc)

Comment: @JasonK Feel free to Upvote and accept my answer if it's helped you. thanks