# change html elements using selenium python

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver as wb
js='document.getElementById("demo").remove()'
wb.Chrome.execute_script()
```

I want to remove Facebook comments
they are in <div aria-label'''''
and run this script with chrome browser
I don't know JavaScript that much
I want to remove comments dynamically on chrome page

Comment: Are you sure that your element with the ID `demo` exists?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running javascript in Selenium using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794087/running-javascript-in-selenium-using-python)

Comment: no that was just an example. i want to get html tag <div aria-label