# How to click the specific button with Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, findelement

Iam trying to find and click on this button. But i always face with "Message: Unable to locate element:"

I try this options, but its doesnt help me:

First: `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(), "CLAIM NOW!")]').click()`

Second: `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@onclick="getClaim()"]').click()`

Third: `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.btn').click()`

Fourth: `driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn btn-lg btn-primary').click()`

Firth: `driver.find_element_by_id('roll_button_container').click()`

Also iam using `time.sleep()` so its not problem with time

> Flow of actions: After I click on the "Claim Now!" a new tab will
> open, but in the previous one (which I am on now) - I will get points.
> And I need to automate this on the project

My almost full code ( cant show you everything as company policy):

```
from selenium  import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox (executable_path = "/Users/USER1/Downloads/AUTOMATION/geckodriver")

driver.get("https://LINK.net/")
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/header/nav/div/div/ul/li[5]/a').click()
time.sleep(3)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/form/div[1]/input').send_keys("login")
time.sleep(3)
el2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/form/div[2]/input').send_keys("password")
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#loginForm > div:nth-child(3) > button:nth-child(1)').click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="test_button"]').click()
time.sleep(3)
#driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(), "CLAIM NOW!")]').click()
#driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@onclick="getClaim()"]').click()
#driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn btn-lg btn-primary').click()
#driver.find_element_by_id('roll_button_container').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.btn').click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.quit()

while True:
  time.sleep(60 * 5)
```

Does anyone can help me to click on button correctly? Thanks a lot.

[image: Button]

Comment: Whats inside `getClaim()`?

Comment: I add screenshot, so anyone can look at. As you can see - its empty, but i dont know what you mean, sorry

Comment: An URL would be more helpful, that screenshot contains no useful data. The js function `getClaim`, that you want to click might contain a page, that you can load without simulate the button click.

Comment: I need to click on the button, not to go to other page

Comment: Okay, show us your code, and do not blur the URL out! We can't help you this way.

Comment: URL will not help any way, but i will add a code

Comment: Oh yeah, I'm right, aren't I?

Comment: I can see only one image in the question, please update the page

Comment: Same picture 3 times. You can check in the edit log.
1, https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXOoY.png
2, https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTaWD.png
3, https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIxC7.png

Comment: Ok, as you cant click on the link inside a question - i will share with you https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezMtL.png

Comment: XPaths need to be corrected //a[contains(text(),'CLAIM N0W!')] or 

//a[@onclick="getClaim()"]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, looks like that the page redirects you to a page that is full of fake ads. By clicking the link, a random ad would pop up each time. Alternatively you can run `getClaim` with selenium as `js`.

You *may* claim your reward by simulating the button press - running the function that the button would run - [only running javascript with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794087/running-javascript-in-selenium-using-python).

```
cmd = "getClaim()"
driver.execute_script(cmd)
```

I hope, as you would say, a "poor indian" could help you.