# insert data into tag with selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, dom, automation

I have a page where I can't click on a button with selenium the html look like this before clicking into button:
[image]

And that's how is look like after pressing the button:
[image]

Is have a way to insert that values into the html tag to get visibility of the element I want in the case button.I try with WebDriverWait and ActionChains but no success.

I execute the javascript code:

```
driver.execute_script('document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].setAttribute("data-whatelement", "button")')
driver.execute_script('document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].setAttribute("data-whatclasses", "Button__StyledButton-iESSlv,dJJJCD Button-dtUzzq kHUYTy")')
```

And still the button element is not visible.How can I get the element try with EC wait and action chain.Is it timeout exception.Any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Using `execute_script` you can run javascript and manipulate the DOM at will. See: [Running javascript in Selenium using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794087/running-javascript-in-selenium-using-python)

So, for example (I'm not entirely sure what you need to do to get visibility of the element), to re-insert the `data-inq-observer` attribute into the `body` tag:

```py
driver.execute_script('document.getElementByTagName("body").setAttribute("data-inq-observer", "1")')
```