# How to click an element with Javascript in Selenium Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

Using selenium, I would like to have a result of an click action on an element in html (HTML4).

The dom in the html is like this

```
<A HREF="javascript:open_login_page();">
<IMG NAME="login_button" SRC="hoge.jpg" alt="login"></A>
```

It seems my Python script successfully obtains the element.

Using the obtained element `a_element`,

```
a_element.get_attribute('href')
```

returns

```
javascript:open_login_page();
```

However, `a_element.click()` raises an error.

How can I have the result?

The expected result is to have another window popup.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running javascript in Selenium using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794087/running-javascript-in-selenium-using-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are basically 4 ways to click in Selenium.

I will use this xpath

```
//IMG[@NAME='login_button']//parent::A
```

**Code trial 1 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//IMG[@NAME='login_button']//parent::A").click()
```

**Code trial 2 :**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//IMG[@NAME='login_button']//parent::A"))).click()
```

**Code trial 3 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//IMG[@NAME='login_button']//parent::A")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

**Code trial 4 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//IMG[@NAME='login_button']//parent::A")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.