# How to execute a Javascript function in python with selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a function called 'checkdata(code)' in javascript, which, as you can see, takes an argument called 'code' to run and returns a 15-char string.

So, I found out (and tested) how to call no-argument functions in javascript, but my problem is that when I call checkdata(code), I always get a 'none' return value. 
This is what I'm doing so far:

```
wd = webdriver.Firefox()
wd.get('My Webpage')
a = wd.execute_script("return checkdata()", code)  //Code is a local variable
                                                   //from my python script
print a
```

I'm making this, since I read it on an unofficial selenium documentation and here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585343/getting-the-return-value-of-javascript-code-in-selenium/5585345#5585345)

But, as I said before, I just keep getting none printed.

How can I call my function passing that parameter?

Comment: See also this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794087/running-javascript-in-selenium-using-python).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Build the string

```
a = wd.execute_script("return checkdata('" + code + "');")
```

Comment: Ah, got it working thanks to you!, here is what my code looks like: `a = local.execute_script(' return checkdata(\"'+code+'\")')
        print a`

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 11):

Rather than building a string (which means you'd have to escape your quotes properly), try this:

```
a = wd.execute_script("return checkdata(arguments[0])", code)
```

Comment: Need an example

Comment: this is an example!