# Python + Selenium WebDriver: open URL in new tab

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a text document with a single URL on every line. I want each URL to be opened in a new tab. Heres what I have so far:

```
tabs = 0
f = open('links.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
for line in f:
    url = line
    driver.execute_script("window.open(url, 'new_window')")
    sleep(7) # time to let tge page load
    tabs = tabs + 1 # to keep track of how many tabs I have
```

This gives me the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "scraper.py", line 100, in
>   
>       driver.execute_script("window.open(url, 'new_window')")   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 635, in execute_script
>       'args': converted_args})['value']   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 320, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
>   line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error:
>   url is not defined

I have tried everything, but can't get it to work. Any Ideas?

Comment: As the error message statues, the js code you're executing has an undefined variable `url`. You need to pass the url as second parameter to the `execute_script` function, as it's currently only defined in your python context. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37337963/2225619

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to pass `url` variable incorrectly in `execute_script`. Do this instead -

```
    tabs = 0
    f = open('links.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    for line in f:
        url = line
        driver.execute_script("window.open(arguments[0])", url)
        sleep(7) # time to let tge page load
        tabs = tabs + 1 # to keep track of how many tabs I have
```

Where, [`arguments[0]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) refers to your url.