# Call a Javascript function in Python - Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have this HTML code I'm proccesing/scrapping with a python script:

```
<a href="javascript:VerMapa('AVDA. DE AMERICA, 2  -33880 POLA DE ALLANDE','RODRIGUEZ-PELAEZ PEÑA, ANA MARIA','AVDA. DE AMERICA, 2  -33880','33880','ALLANDE','183','178')"><img src="../../Fijos/Img/VerMapa.jpg" alt="" width="25" height="24" border="0">&nbsp;<br>Ver Mapa</a>
```

This is the definition of the function:

```
function VerMapa(direccion,farmacia,domicilio,CP,municipio, numeroOficina,identidad) {
    window.open("googleMaps.aspDir="+direccion+"&Far="+farmacia+"&Dom="+domicilio+"&CP="+CP+"&Mun="+municipio+"&NO="+numeroOficina+"&Id="+identidad+"&",'Lista','toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,status=yes,screenX=50,top=50,width=740,height=530');
}
```

I need to make a call to `VerMapa('AVDA. DE AMERICA, 2  -33880 POLA DE ALLANDE','RODRIGUEZ-PELAEZ PEÑA, ANA MARIA','AVDA. DE AMERICA, 2  -33880','33880','ALLANDE','183','178')` javascript function in the href attribute and get the HTML code returned.

I have checked spider-monkey and PyV8 but I think they can't help me here. spider-monkey is clear  telling you can´t call a javascript defined function.

I'm now trying with Selenium, but I don't know how I can get the source code back to python.

By know I just have implemented a test script and managed to load the requested page in a browser window.

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://www.farmasturias.org/GESCOF/cms/Guardias/FarmaciaBuscar.asp?IdMenu=111")
htmlCode = browser.execute_script("return VerMapa('AVDA. DE AMERICA, 2  -33880 POLA DE ALLANDE','RODRIGUEZ-PELAEZ PEÑA, ANA MARIA','AVDA. DE AMERICA, 2  -33880','33880','ALLANDE','183','178')")
print htmlCode;
```

1.- I am not getting anything in htmlCode var. ¿How can I get back the source code  generated by the javascript function? I have taken the syntax from this post [Getting the return value of Javascript code in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585343/getting-the-return-value-of-javascript-code-in-selenium/5585345#5585345)

2.- Is there any way to use Selenium without opening any browser window?

Comment: I have tried the same code with java and a new pop up window is populated. After executing javascript and using print htmlCode, do you need the html source of that pop up window where map is shown?

Comment: Maybe I make not it clear. The code pops up a new window with the expected content, but nothing is returned in htmlCode var. I'm trying to get in that var the source code of the page.

Comment: @DavidCasillas Do you want the source code of the main page or the newly opened pop-up window?

Comment: The on created for the pop-up window.

Answer (score 0):

The `VerMapa` function doesn't have a return. That's why your `htmlCode` variable doesn't show anything.

To get the source of the new window, first call `VerMapa`, then switch to the new window, then get the source.

```
# get all open windows
handles = set(broswer.window_handles)

# remove the current window from the set
handles.remove(browser.current_window_handle)

# switch to the other window
browser.switch_to_window(handles.pop())

# get the source of that window
htmlCode = browser.page_source
```