# Selenium WebDriver's SendKeys too slow to fill in <textarea> input

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm having an issue that SendKeys is too slow. I need to add around 1300 lines to textarea

```
<textarea id="ctl00_phMainContent_KeywordForm_ControlPanel_txtKeywords" onload="CountLines(this);" onkeypress="CountLines(this);" wrap="off" cols="100" rows="6" name="ctl00$phMainContent$KeywordForm$ControlPanel$txtKeywords"></textarea>
```

The thing is my login to the website expires and I have to re-login and do that again infinite loop...

Can anyone help me how to appeand the text (lines) Instantly? maybe some Javascript? or Ctrl+c + Ctrl+v? Anyone have a working code?

Comment: Does it differ in what browser you use?

Comment: @Arran I use Phantomjs (FF)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run JavaScript code in the context of browser opened by a WebDriver.

Use JavaScript evalution to modify HTML DOM tree directly and set `<textarea>` value.

Evaluating JavaScript in Selenium (Python):

[Getting the return value of Javascript code in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585343/getting-the-return-value-of-javascript-code-in-selenium/5585345#5585345)

Setting `<textarea>` value in JavaScript:

```
 document.getElementById("ctl00_phMainContent_KeywordForm_ControlPanel_txtKeywords").value = "Foobar"
```

Comment: thanks! Seems like this one will work! I just can't figure out how to use my list in the "value" part... I read text file lines and want it to be the value. (Needs to be with lines as well not one line) the value located in keywordurl and here is how I get it http://pastebin.com/v6gudYXK

Comment: Your JavaScript is not probably correct. Check the Firefox's Web Console for JavaScript syntax errors, etc. Remember properly quote strings.

Comment: thank you for the solution. It works. But one limitation you cannot add using javascript value with separate lines only if it was 1 line of information I would be able to use it. And because my text files is url in each line I need to paste it exactly as in text file. So a ctrl +c + ctrl + v should be the only way to do it.

Comment: Naturally, you can insert line breaks to <textarea>, as millions of pages are doing it every day. You only need to figure out how to do it in JavaScript. I cannot outright tell how to do it, so I suggest you open a separate question for it.