# How to know if the javascript code has been executed in Selenium Java?

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this part of the code in my **Selenium Webdriver** test in **java**. I use this javascript code to scroll to a particular value `i` in the page.

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("scroll(0,"+i+");");
```

`scroll(0,y)` doesn't return a value. Is there any way to know if this script has been executed ?

Comment: Why don't you debug and check it if it has really executed or not

Comment: After the scroll , I take screenshots. But, I noticed that the javascript code and getScreenshots are not in sync when it comes to a dynamic page

Comment: Even i take the screenshot after scrolling the page. It works fine. Wat do u mean by 'dynamic page'?

Comment: A page containing dynamic content. Say for example 9gag.com whose content keep loading dynamically.

Comment: what does the `"+i+"` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try getting a return value from the script which then you can handle from Selenium itself? Try using:

```
if(window.pageYOffset!= undefined){
  return [pageXOffset, pageYOffset];
}
```

This will return the offsets for you after the scroll. You can then assert if this scroll position is the one you want or not.

Further detail on this approach can be found here:

[Getting the return value of Javascript code in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585343/getting-the-return-value-of-javascript-code-in-selenium)

[How to get scrollbar position with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481350/retrieve-scrollbar-position-with-javascript)