# Is it possible to calculate the performance testing through selenium with python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Is it possible to calculate the performance testing through selenium with python?

If it is possible, how should I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the return value of Javascript code in Selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585343/getting-the-return-value-of-javascript-code-in-selenium)

Comment: I suppose that this is browser-specific. Please edit your question and add the tag for the browser driver you are using, e.g. ChromeDriver

Comment: Related [Browser performance tests through selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27596229/browser-performance-tests-through-selenium).

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is not the right tool to use for performance testing.

jmeter is a great tool for this. You would be able to see the response for each request.

Comment: Can you suggest the tools which are efficient.

Comment: jmeter is a great tools for this.