# Browser performance tests through selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, performance-testing

We are using `protractor` for testing internal AngularJS applications.

Besides functional tests, we check for performance regressions with the help of [`protractor-perf`](http://npmjs.org/package/protractor-perf) which is based on nodejs [`browser-perf`](https://github.com/axemclion/browser-perf) library. Because, ["Performance is a feature"](http://blog.codinghorror.com/performance-is-a-feature/).

With `protractor-perf` we can measure and assert different performance characteristics while making browser actions, [for example](http://blog.nparashuram.com/2014/11/protractor-perf-performance-regression.html):

```
browser.get('http://www.angularjs.org');

perf.start(); // Start measuring the metrics
element(by.model('todoText')).sendKeys('write a protractor test');
element(by.css('[value="add"]')).click();
perf.stop(); // Stop measuring the metrics 

if (perf.isEnabled) { // Is perf measuring enabled ?
    // Check for perf regressions, just like you check for functional regressions
    expect(perf.getStats('meanFrameTime')).toBeLessThan(60); 
};
```

---

Now, for an another internal application we have a set of selenium-based tests written in Python.

Is it possible to check for performance regressions with selenium-python, or should I rewrite the tests using `protractor` to be able to write browser performance tests?

Comment: Hope this might [help](https://gist.github.com/klepikov/5457750)...a detailed discussion about this was given in [GTAC - 2013](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0_kAPWSZNY4).

Comment: @VivekSingh it really does. The idea presented during this google test automation conference talk is awesome and very much related to what I am asking about. I'll try to develop the idea in a python-specific manner and I hope I'll submit an answer here. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a possibility to get closer to [what `browser-perf` is doing](https://github.com/axemclion/browser-perf/wiki/Architecture) by collecting the [chrome performance logs](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/logging/performance-log) and analyzing them.

To [get performance logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27644615/getting-chrome-performance-and-tracing-logs), turn on `performance` logs by tweaking `loggingPrefs` desired capability:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
caps['loggingPrefs'] = {'performance': 'ALL'}
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps)

driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com')

logs = [json.loads(log['message'])['message'] for log in driver.get_log('performance')]

with open('devtools.json', 'wb') as f:
    json.dump(logs, f)

driver.close()
```

At this point, `devtools.json` file would contain a bunch of trace records:

```
[
  {
    "params": {
      "timestamp": 1419571233.19293,
      "frameId": "16639.1",
      "requestId": "16639.1",
      "loaderId": "16639.2",
      "type": "Document",
      "response": {
        "mimeType": "text/plain",
        "status": 200,
        "fromServiceWorker": false,
        "encodedDataLength": -1,
        "headers": {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          "Content-Type": "text/plain;charset=US-ASCII"
        },
        "url": "data:,",
        "statusText": "OK",
        "connectionId": 0,
        "connectionReused": false,
        "fromDiskCache": false
      }
    },
    "method": "Network.responseReceived"
  },
  {
    "params": {
      "timestamp": 1419571233.19294,
      "encodedDataLength": 0,
      "requestId": "16639.1"
    },
    "method": "Network.loadingFinished"
  },
  ..
]
```

Now, the question is, what to do with it.

One option that was initially suggested [during the Google Test Automation Conference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0_kAPWSZNY4) is to submit the logs to [webpagetest.org](http://www.webpagetest.org/). There is an example *in java* available [here](https://gist.github.com/klepikov/5457750), but, at the moment, I had no luck implementing it in Python.

In theory, the UI report generated by webpagetest.org would look like this:

[image]

They also provide the metrics in JSON/XML and other formats that can be further analyzed.

This is really something, thanks to Vivek Singh for the pointing comment.

---

browser-perf also uses the logging functionality to pick up the tracing logs, and analyzes the data.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to do performance regression testing with Selenium. However as you might have already noted. The core essence of Selenium is that it mimics user behavior. This means that Selenium will only perform the action (e.g. clicking on the button) if the user is able to perform the same action. Also taking into account certain code, workarounds (i.e. hard waits,  various checks and custom code), required to even be able to run the Selenium script. This means that the "definition" of performance testing using Selenium will be slightly different compared to traditional performance testing.

What you will want to do is have a timer (start/stop) for each action Selenium is performing. For example: Clicking on a button and log this to a file for later use.

Using Selenium you can create a performance baseline and from there on onwards compare each consecutive result with the baseline. This will give you statistics that you can then use for further analysis.

Selenium nor Webdriver (Selenium 2.0) come with this feature out of the box. So some custom coding needs to happen for this to work.

Comment: This is an interesting and solid point. This is something I personally like to point out - `selenium` is just a browser automation tool to mimic user actions on the page. But, that `browser-perf` tool is definitely [doing a lot on top of it](https://github.com/axemclion/browser-perf/wiki/Architecture) - uses `about:tracing` to gather performance metrics. I guess I should either follow the approach you've suggested (stick to a baseline), or switch to `protractor` which is something we started to use extensively anyway. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Performance testing through Selenium is not advised because it is not optimised for the job. It has been listed as one of the *worst practices* by the Selenium [team](https://selenium.dev/documentation/en/worst_practices/performance_testing/):

> It may seem ideal to performance test in the context of the user but a suite of WebDriver tests are subjected to many points of external and internal fragility which are beyond your control; for example browser startup speed, speed of HTTP servers, response of third party servers that host JavaScript or CSS, and the instrumentation penalty of the WebDriver implementation itself. Variation at these points will cause variation in your results. It is difficult to separate the difference between the performance of your website and the performance of external resources, and it is also hard to tell what the performance penalty is for using WebDriver in the browser, especially if you are injecting scripts.