# Getting chrome performance and tracing logs

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to follow the idea suggested in the [Web Performance Testing with WebDriver](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0_kAPWSZNY4) google test automation conference talk and ChromeDriver ["Performance Log" documentation page](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/logging/performance-log) to get the trace data which I want to submit to [webpagetest](http://www.webpagetest.org/) for performance analysis later.

How can I retrieve performance logs using *python selenium bindings*?

---

I've tried to print out `log_types` available in the driver instance

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com')

print driver.log_types

driver.close()
```

but got only

```
[u'browser', u'driver']
```

And I don't see a relevant [command-line switch](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Performance logs are **disabled by default**.

To enable it, use [`DesiredCapabilities`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#desired-capabilities) and configure `loggingPrefs`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
 #as per latest docs
caps['goog:loggingPrefs'] = {'performance': 'ALL'}
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps)

driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com')

for entry in driver.get_log('performance'):
    print(entry)

driver.quit()
```

This results into a bunch of tracing log entries printed on the console:

```
{u'timestamp': 1419487459178, u'message': u'{"message":{"method":"Network.responseReceived","params":{"frameId":"2105.1","loaderId":"2105.2","requestId":"2105.1","response":{"connectionId":0,"connectionReused":false,"encodedDataLength":-1,"fromDiskCache":false,"fromServiceWorker":false,"headers":{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*","Content-Type":"text/plain;charset=US-ASCII"},"mimeType":"text/plain","status":200,"statusText":"OK","url":"data:,"},"timestamp":1419487458.92934,"type":"Document"}},"webview":"2C66E956-A48B-456B-8A4E-1022F699AA92"}', u'level': u'INFO'}
{u'timestamp': 1419487459178, u'message': u'{"message":{"method":"Network.loadingFinished","params":{"encodedDataLength":0,"requestId":"2105.1","timestamp":1419487458.92936}},"webview":"2C66E956-A48B-456B-8A4E-1022F699AA92"}', u'level': u'INFO'}
{u'timestamp': 1419487459178, u'message': u'{"message":{"method":"Page.frameNavigated","params":{"frame":{"id":"2105.1","loaderId":"2105.2","mimeType":"text/plain","securityOrigin":"://","url":"data:,"}}},"webview":"2C66E956-A48B-456B-8A4E-1022F699AA92"}', u'level': u'INFO'}
...
```

Comment: I know this answer is super old, but do you know if there is a way to get only the "Network" events (i.e. what you'd see when you go to the "Network" tab on Chrome's Developer Tools) . I can parse what I need out of the log, but I'm thinking there is a more efficient way and I'm having some trouble figuring out the docs. Thanks!

Comment: Been looking for this answer for awhile now. Thanks!

Comment: For newer version of Chrome, you have to use
`caps["goog:loggingPrefs"] = {"performance": "ALL"}`.

Comment: The message entry inside the log is a string  log need to be serialized to JSON. E.g.
import json
s =  log['message']
json_acceptable_string = s.replace("'", "\"")
d = json.loads(json_acceptable_string)

Comment: The API docs for `DesiredCapabilities` clearly state: "Note: Always use '.copy()' on the DesiredCapabilities object to avoid the side effects of altering the Global class instance."
Therefore `caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME` should be `caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()`

Comment: `desired_capabilities` has been removed according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76430192/getting-typeerror-webdriver-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-desi) post,so the newest way looks like this :
`options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.set_capability('goog:loggingPrefs', {'performance': 'ALL'})`

Comment: @zionpi works for selenium 4.13, ty!!

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement the @Rajesh answer, in case doesn't work you. It could be due you are using an old chromedriver version, so in that case, it would be `loggingPrefs` instead of `goog:loggingPrefs`.

```
caps['loggingPrefs'] = {'performance': 'ALL'}
```

For more info, look at this:

[Getting console.log output from Chrome with Selenium Python API bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907180/getting-console-log-output-from-chrome-with-selenium-python-api-bindings)