# Selenium get http request ajax url after button click

Tags: ajax, selenium, http, url

I need to get the http request URL when a button is clicked in a webpage programatically.
I am using selenium to trace the button and I am performing click on the button. on click of the button it makes a http request and the same can be traced in the network tab of the browser.

How can i get the request URL programatically once I trigger the button click using selenium.

Any other tools or libraries that I can use to achieve the same functions is also ok for me. I just need to be able to get the URL after button click programatically. This is a dynamic URL which changes periodically and the objective is to automate the download process through code.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Do you see any changes in HTML as well when the button is clicked ?

Comment: Not sure but there might be. But the URL is not there in the HTML. It must be an ajax call from a button inside the shadow DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JavaScript executor to get network data. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45859018/5966329
get request/response data from there.

```
DesiredCapabilities d = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();    
LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
logPrefs.enable(LogType.PERFORMANCE, Level.ALL);
d.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(d);
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
LogEntries les = driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.PERFORMANCE);
for (LogEntry le : les) {
  System.out.println(le.getMessage());
}
```

Python Equivalent:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import 
DesiredCapabilities

caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME

caps['goog:loggingPrefs'] = {'performance': 'ALL'}
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps)

driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com')
for entry in driver.get_log('performance'):
    print(entry)
```

Please refer thread for more info [python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27644635/5966329)

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated! Is there any python equivalent to this?

Comment: Ravi, Please add below desired capability in python driver creation step. 

    desiredcaps = {'loggingPrefs': {'performance': 'ALL'}}

Comment: Thank you! I will try this out and update later. Very much appreciate your help!