# Getting TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument ‘desired_capabilities’ when using Appium with Selenium 4.10

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, appium, python-appium

Error:
`HOOK-ERROR in before_scenario: TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'desired_capabilities'`

Hello, we currently cannot run our script together with the latest Selenium 4.10. Is this Appium error or Python error?

Here is the capabilities that we used. We're currently trying to get the capabilities for platformName by `targetOS = self.driver.capabilities['platformName']` but we're hit with this error

```
capabilities = {
    "platformName": "Android",
    "appium:platformVersion": "11.0",
    "appium:deviceName": "emulator-5554",
    "appium:app": "/Users/faithberroya/Downloads/test.apk",
    "appium:automationName": "UiAutomator2",
    "appium:appPackage": "com.test.school.assignment.rc",
    "appium:appActivity": "com.test.school.assignment.ui.SplashActivity"
}

# launch app
context.driver = webdriver.Remote("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub", capabilities)
# add wait time
context.driver.implicitly_wait(20)
# app
context.app = Application(context.driver)
```

Current pip list

```
Appium-Python-Client     2.10.1
behave                   1.2.6
certifi                  2023.5.7
pip                      23.1.1
requests                 2.31.0
selenium                 4.9.0
```

Answer (score 21):

This is due to changes in `selenium` `4.10.0`:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9f5801c82fb3be3d5850707c46c3f8176e3ccd8e

[image: Changes_in_selenium_4_10_0]

Note that `desired_capabilities` has been removed from the `__init__`, but there is now another way of passing it in. See https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/upgrade_to_selenium_4/#capabilities for the documentation on how to pass in desired capabilities when using `selenium` `4.10.0` (or newer).

Here's a code snippet on using capabilities in the new version:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions
options = FirefoxOptions()
cloud_options = {}
cloud_options['build'] = "build_1"
cloud_options['name'] = "test_abc"
options.set_capability('cloud:options', cloud_options)
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub", options=options)
```

Comment: I downgraded `selenium==4.9.1` and it worked for my case

Comment: what is the solution for desired_capabilities? this is for set_capabilities. what i want to `desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME`

Answer (score 3):

I face similar issue. By default Appium python client uses latest selenium release(4.10.0). So i downgraded the version to 4.9.0 with Appium-python-client as 2.9.0 and it worked fine.

Comment: Same solution for now we have the latest Appium but downgraded the selenium to 4.9.0

Comment: Downgrading is not a solution, it is a feature change. you will eventually get into this situation in the future. what we need are examples how to rewrite our code so it work with the new version.

Comment: @MortenB I think it is useful to have answers that show how to patch the client code, as well as answers that indicate which version to downgrade to in order to keep old code working. This answer contributes a useful piece of information.

Comment: what is the solution for robotframework if I need to run the seleium 4.10? I cannot downgrade

Answer (score 1):

Appium-Python-Client，The version is too high, try version Appium-Python-Client==1.2.0