# Unable to get performance logs

Tags: performance, firefox, selenium, logging, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get performance logs using Selenium WebDriver with following code:

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
logPrefs.enable(LogType.PERFORMANCE, Level.ALL);
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(cap);

driver.get("http://www.google.com");

System.out.println("Performance: " + driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.PERFORMANCE).getAll());

for (LogEntry entry : driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.PERFORMANCE)) {
    System.out.println("Entry: " + entry.toString());
}

driver.quit();
```

After running above code, I didn't get anything in return as logs. If you see output of line:

```
System.out.println("Performance: " + driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.PERFORMANCE).getAll());
```

it's returning empty array. Can you please suggest what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Yup @alecxe is correct as per my knowledge. But u can try out [this](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/automate-page-load-performance-testing-with-firebug-and-selenium/) site for some other way arounds...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, performance logs are not available for `Firefox WebDriver` at the moment.

You can switch to [`ChromeDriver`](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/logging/performance-log) to make it work, this is what I'm sure is working:

- [Getting chrome performance and tracing logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27644615/getting-chrome-performance-and-tracing-logs)
- [Browser performance tests through selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27596229/browser-performance-tests-through-selenium/)