# How to do Performance Testing with selenium?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, performance-testing

I am testing fresher.. I am working on selenium past 4 months.

**Is it selenium support to do the Performance testing.. if it is supporting then how to do.. can any one provide information?**

Comment: Check this out... [performance testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27596229/browser-performance-tests-through-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine selenium purpose (to a more like performance test tool) Using selenium script, you can run it through a proxy server and capture the HTTP traffic. With this traffic,you should be able to run some simple checks to see if application performance has degraded, or hook it up to JMeter and perform appropriate assertions (Look into JMeter and see the integration with WebDriver).

Hope this helps

Here are alternative resources to give you headway

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qQgDDAan4rM

https://www.igvita.com/2012/08/28/web-performance-power-tool-http-archive-har/

https://gist.github.com/tourdedave/bc4b75fd6cdc1eef7860

http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/