# Does Webdriver Affect Performance

Tags: selenium, protractor, performance-testing

**Question**: Does using Selenium Webdriver have an impact on browser performance?

**Background**: I've been reading up on browser performance metrics, just using the browser dev tools but also looking into the [Navigation Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API) and [Resource Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Resource_Timing_API/Using_the_Resource_Timing_API).  There are also some packages out there that implement these (or seem to implement them, I didn't dig into the source code) - such as [browser perf](https://github.com/axemclion/browser-perf).

Considering these hook into the browser environment via `browser.executeScript()` to return objects from `window.performance`, would this impact actual performance (and ultimately skew my data when compared to a user checking these metrics manually)?

Comment: You may want to use the browser to collect performance metrics so that you don't have to inject javascript. E.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27653643/604131

Comment: Did not see that post when I was searching earlier.  Good info, thanks.