# Python 3.4, how to execute Javascript on a website and catch result? (like it appears in the browser)

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, python-3.4

So I'm making this scraper program but I would need to catch information that doesn't show up in the source code.

Here is what it looks like in the source :

```
<td><script> <type="text/javascript">SCRIPT("SUPERLONGVARIABLE")</script></td>
```

And I'd like to be able to catch the result (which is just a short string of about 5 - 20 letters).

Any idea how I could do that? Not sure if the requests module can help me on this one.

Thanks in advance guys! :)

Comment: you want to execute javascript or scrape javascript content?

Comment: I wanna execute it and the catch the result it would show in a regular browser

Comment: use `selenium`  look at [this](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) good luck

Comment: Okay thanks! If I understand well, driver.execute_script("") would be what I'm looking for right?

Comment: Awesome! But just one thing, I'd need to "catch" the result of the javascript (it's just a rather short string), can I do it with this or can I just execute it ? (because executing it on it self won't be enough)

Comment: updated answer. tldr; yes, you can

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you'd want to learn how to use selenium for python : [link](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/).
By utilizing `driver.execute_script('foo')`, you can actually get the result of that execution.

For simliar answer, look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585343/getting-the-return-value-of-javascript-code-in-selenium/5585345#5585345) on so

Comment: My bad I thought I had answered, I tried with the command I wrote on the last comment but the thing is it litterally goes through firefox (as in the firefox page pops up) and I don't end up getting the result I want in python (meaning the decoded string)