# Data scraping from a webpage with javascript using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests-html

I'm trying to scrape the title off of a webpage. Initially, I tried using BeautifulSoup but found out that the page itself wouldn't load without Javascript. So I'm using some code that I found off Google that use the request-html library:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
session = HTMLSession()
resp = session.get("https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/t1/tbl1/en/tv.action?pid=3210001601")
resp.html.render()
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.html.html, "lxml")

soup.find_all('h1')
```

But there's always an error along the line of:

```
D:\Python\TitleSraping\venv\Scripts\python.exe "D:/Python/TitleSraping/venv/Text Scraping.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\TitleSraping\venv\lib\site-packages\pyppeteer\execution_context.py", line 106, in evaluateHandle
    'userGesture': True,
pyppeteer.errors.NetworkError: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Cannot find context with specified id

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python/TitleSraping/venv/Text Scraping.py", line 5, in <module>
    resp.html.render()
  File "D:\Python\TitleSraping\venv\lib\site-packages\requests_html.py", line 598, in render
    content, result, page = self.session.loop.run_until_complete(self._async_render(url=self.url, script=script, sleep=sleep, wait=wait, content=self.html, reload=reload, scrolldown=scrolldown, timeout=timeout, keep_page=keep_page))
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 584, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "D:\Python\TitleSraping\venv\lib\site-packages\requests_html.py", line 531, in _async_render
    content = await page.content()
  File "D:\Python\TitleSraping\venv\lib\site-packages\pyppeteer\page.py", line 780, in content
    return await frame.content()
  File "D:\Python\TitleSraping\venv\lib\site-packages\pyppeteer\frame_manager.py", line 379, in content
    '''.strip())
  File "D:\Python\TitleSraping\venv\lib\site-packages\pyppeteer\frame_manager.py", line 295, in evaluate
    pageFunction, *args, force_expr=force_expr)
  File "D:\Python\TitleSraping\venv\lib\site-packages\pyppeteer\execution_context.py", line 55, in evaluate
    pageFunction, *args, force_expr=force_expr)
  File "D:\Python\TitleSraping\venv\lib\site-packages\pyppeteer\execution_context.py", line 109, in evaluateHandle
    _rewriteError(e)
  File "D:\Python\TitleSraping\venv\lib\site-packages\pyppeteer\execution_context.py", line 238, in _rewriteError
    raise type(error)(msg)
pyppeteer.errors.NetworkError: Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Does anyone know what this means? I'm quite new to this, so I apologize if I'm using any terminology improperly.

Answer (score 1):

As Ivan said, here you have full code: sleep=1, keep_page=True make the trick

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = HTMLSession()
resp = session.get("https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/t1/tbl1/en/tv.action?pid=3210001601")
resp.html.render(sleep=1, keep_page=True)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.html.html, "lxml")
print(soup.find_all('title'))
```

Response:

```
[<title>
    Milled wheat and wheat flour produced</title>]
```

Comment: hmm, i wish this what was i was getting, but i still seem to get the same error

Comment: Did you tried with my code? I run in my console (Python 3.7) and its working like a charm. Please, paste your code now to fix it :)

Comment: So... i did try your code... sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't and i honestly don't know why anymore

Comment: I'll try to replicate it

Comment: I tried 10 times one behind other and works...try to put sleep=2 (2 seconds) if your internet is slow up to 5 sec.
sleep – Integer, if provided, of how many long to sleep after initial render.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bug in underlying library `puppeteer`, caused by processing some javascript. Here's one workaround from https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests-html/issues/251, maybe it'll help.

`resp.html.render(sleep=1, keep_page=True)`

Comment: I tried it out, i still seem to be getting a similar error

Comment: You might try to increase `sleep` parameter. If your page is heavy and machine is slow, it can help.

Comment: Note for my future self, or, other people: I try specifying only `keep_page=True`, and it's enough to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the JS because if you don't load it the HTML code wont load. You can use Selenium

Comment: hmm, I'm trying to follow along to this tutorial http://theautomatic.net/2019/01/19/scraping-data-from-javascript-webpage-python/ not sure how it works there

Comment: The problem is specifically with the page you want to scrape, because it has security against scrapers.

Answer (score 0):

Try Seleneum.

Seleneum is a library that allows programs to interact with web pages by taking control of the browser.

Here is an example in 
[an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585343/getting-the-return-value-of-javascript-code-in-selenium/5585345#5585345)
to someone else's question.

Comment: hmm, I'm trying to follow along to this tutorial http://theautomatic.net/2019/01/19/scraping-data-from-javascript-webpage-python/ not sure how it works there