# Selenium thinks button is clickable when it's disabled and raises WebDriverException

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I know there's someone else having the same problem as me, but it turns out he's using a different code as me. (I'm **NOT** having the same problem with this : [Selenium identifies the button as clickable when it wasn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62683452/selenium-thinks-button-is-clickable-when-it-isnt)) So, apparently I've tried to make the page refreshes everytime the button is **unclickable or disabled** using the WebDriverException error.

So, everytime the Selenium drops an error of **WebDriverException** which an error that occurs if you attempt to click a disabled object (If I'm not wrong), it'll **refresh the page until it's enabled.** It has worked for a few days back, but for some reason I don't know what I've done, It suddenly starts malfunctioning?.

It acts like nothing happened, and drops no error even though the element is clearly disabled. I tried printing the variable just to check if the element actually stored in the variable. But, it did. So I don't know what could be causing the problem. I've put the code below, every helpful answer I appreciate them!. Thank you!.

```
purchasenow = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[5]/div/div/button[2]")
purchasenow.click()
print(purchasenow)

while True:
    try:
        purchasenow.click()
        newtime()
        print("[INFO :] ORDER BUTTON ENABLED!, ATTEMPTING TO PUT ITEM IN CART...")
        webhook = DiscordWebhook(url=logs, content='[INFO :] ORDER BUTTON ENABLED!, ATTEMPTING TO PUT ITEM IN CART...')
        if withlogging == "y":
            response = webhook.execute()
        break
    except WebDriverException:
        newtime()
        print("[INFO :] ORDER BUTTON DISABLED!, REFRESHING THE PAGE...")
        webhook = DiscordWebhook(url=logs, content='[INFO :] ORDER BUTTON DISABLED!, REFRESHING THE PAGE...')
        if withlogging == "y":
            response = webhook.execute()
        browser.refresh()
        continue
```

EDIT [12/10/2020] : Tried making it sure with the is_enabled(), somehow it was detected as True or clickable. Still looking for possible solutions, please let me know in the Answers!.

Comment: add the html of the element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refreshing the webpage multiple times wouldn't ensure that the element would turn clickable instantly on page load. Modern websites are increasingly implementing [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/), [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/), [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), [Ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp), [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/), [Ember.js](https://www.emberjs.com/), [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/overview.html), etc. to render the dynamic elements within the [DOM tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes). Hence to invoke `click()` on a [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) there is a necessity to wait for the element and its children to completely render and become **interactable**.

---

### element_to_be_clickable()

[`element_to_be_clickable`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable) is the expectation for checking an element is visible and enabled such that you can click it. It is [defined](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.html#element_to_be_clickable) as:

```
def element_to_be_clickable(locator):
    """ An Expectation for checking an element is visible and enabled such that
    you can click it."""
    def _predicate(driver):
    element = visibility_of_element_located(locator)(driver)
    if element and element.is_enabled():
        return element
    else:
        return False

    return _predicate
```

---

So ideally, to wait for the button to be clickable you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[5]/div/div/button[2]"))).click()
```

**Note**: You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Selenium identifies the button as clickable when it wasn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62683452/selenium-identifies-the-button-as-clickable-when-it-wasnt/65223274#65223274)
- [Get HTML source of WebElement in Selenium WebDriver using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263824/get-html-source-of-webelement-in-selenium-webdriver-using-python/65037421#65037421)