# Webdriver add bookmarklet to driver on driver creation, or save bookmarklet to bookmarks - Without loading profiles

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, google-chrome, bookmarklet

## Question

I want to add a custom bookmarklet (bookmark that is pure JavaScript code) to a webdriver so it appears in the bookmarks toolbar. This can either be at creation time via add_extension, or after page load.

How can I add this bookmarklet to bookamrks toolbar WITHOUT user interaction, and WITHOUT loading a profile? Any ideas welcomed

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_extension(r'C:\path\to\extension.crx')

# Have tried the below but doesn't open the add page to bookmarks?
"""actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'd')
actions.perform()
"""
```

Comment: Why? What are you trying to accomplish by adding this bookmark?

Comment: I want to add a bookmarklet, the bookmarklet contains javascript code that the user can click to do “X”.  its a long story as to why. @DMart

Comment: How are you using selenium? What is your ultimate goal?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute javascript arbitrarly in selenium. You don't need a book mark to do this.
See this example:

```
driver.execute_script("return true")
```

And this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5585345/1387701

Comment: I should’ve specified im aware of this, but im using selenium for an odd use case. I dont want to auto run js. I want users to click on bookmarks. For example one bookmarklet i want to make is a table of instructions that is shown to a user om the current page when they click the instructions bookmark. @DMart

Comment: What users? If you're using selenium you're using code to control the browser.

Comment: Sounds like you might want to create a browser extension instead.

Comment: Im making a program that uses selenium, yes im looking at apps now :)

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured out 2 ways to do this and ultimately its not worth it lol.
I will edit my comment when home to include how