# how to get data(series) from highcharts with python

Tags: highcharts

ex url: (I'm sorry, but I think I need to remove the url due to personal reasons. you can use any other url containing highcharts.)

i want to get data(series) from highcharts with python3

Specifically, ex url-> highchart -> rightmost value (wednesday aug 04, 2021 serues  1:70.38)

i tried to get these values with selenium and many other stackoverflow's code. but i couldn't .
pleeeeeeeease let me know

Comment: Hi @hyopark, You can get the chart object by using this JS script: `$(document.getElementsByClassName('chart')[0]).highcharts()`. To get the last point data use: `$(document.getElementsByClassName('chart')[0]).highcharts().series[0].points[64]`

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know selenium. I just run the above code in the browser console and it worked. Maybe you need to use some timeout before executing the script?

Comment: oh, There is no need to say sorry! :) your commant was verrryyyyyy helpful!  Anyway,   you got the data with your code, so it's worth a try. I'll try everything~! If I solve this problem, I'll comment again. Thanks again ppotaczek! :)

Comment: It's me again ppotaczek! I've just solved the problem!!I found out in StackOverflow why 'none' was returned.  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585343/getting-the-return-value-of-javascript-code-in-selenium] - "if variable is not defined, it returns None " So I changed the code you gave me to be more specific like"return parseFloat($(document.getElementsByClassName('chart')[0]).highcharts().series[0].points[64].series.yData[64])". Finally, It's working! I'm soooo happy!!! thank you so much ppotaczek!.

Comment: #2  
I'm sorry, but I think I need to remove the url due to personal reasons. I'll save the second comment for others.
nice to meet you @ppotaczek. :) Thank you for your comment. I tried to your js code like ` from selenium import webdriver import time driver = webdriver.Chrome() url = "URL containing highcharts" driver.get(url) time.sleep(5) temp=driver.execute_script("$(document.getElementsByClassName('chart'[0]).highcharts().series[0].points[64];") print(temp) temp=driver.execute_script("$(document.getElementsByClassName('chart'[0]).highcharts()") print(temp)` but it return none.